# Is there any classes or structures that can make matrix operation in C++ more handy?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writting a program in Visual Studio using MFC dialog based application.
I have 5 matrix in my program where I have to add two of them and multiply other 2 of them and then subtract the result of multiplication from the summed value to get the 5th matrix.
Some time I have to square the summed matrix also so it is quite laborious to write the full code...
So one way is to write the code straight forward in C++ using array...But if I want to multiply two matrices or sum them directly as can be done in MatLab, is it possible in C++?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

Boost has a good library for linear algebra: [Boost.uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm).

It includes a convenient matrix class, as well as built in matrix arithmetic operations.

Comment: uBLAS is indeed great and it is pretty easy to use it in conjunction with a LAPACK library, making it quite useful if you need to perform high-performance matrix computations.

Answer (score 0):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is very powerful and highly optimized. It supports both dynamic matrices (size unknown at compile time) and statically sized matrices. Take a look at the [tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialCore.html).

Answer (score 0):

[What's a good C++ library for matrix operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562231/whats-a-good-c-library-for-matrix-operations)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the gmtl (generic math template library).